# Ubuntu 23.10 - Nework interface settings visually revert after closing configuration dialog and internally revert after rebooting

Tags: networking, network-manager, 23.10, static-ip

I'm trying to *permanently* set a static IPv4 address on a specific network interface in Ubuntu 23.10, via the "Network" menu in the settings app. However, when I leave the network interface's configuration dialog, and re-open it, the settings have been reverted visually. If I use `ip a` the configuration is still applied, so not a huge deal. But then when I reset the system, the visual & internal configurations are cleared.

Is this intended behavior? I see that I can set things via a `.yaml` configuration file, but the GUI tool seemed apt; assuming it held its configuration.

Comment: Turns out I was just missing the Gateway parameter, not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was setting the Address & Netmask, but not the Gateway. It's weird that the connection took at all missing that, but I digress.